# Can't Save to Database

Tags: php, database, pdo

I've been looking for a week now, for whats wrong. I am still not able to find out what goed wrong!
I hope somebody can see whats wrong?

registration.php:

```
<form action="saveregistration.php" onsubmit="return validateForm()" class="pure-form" id="form" method="POST"> 
<label for="initials">Initials:</label><input type="text" name="initials" id="initials" placeholder="initials" required><br />
<label for="firstname">First name:</label><input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" placeholder="firstname" required><br />
<label for="surname">Surname:</label><input type="text" name="surname" id="surname" placeholder="surname" required><br />
<label for="country">Country:</label><input type="text" name="country" id="country" placeholder="country" required><br />
<label for="state">State:</label><input type="text" name="state" id="state" placeholder="state" ><br />
<label for="province">Province:</label><input type="text" name="province" id="province" placeholder="province" required><br />
<label for="city">City:</label><input type="text" name="city" id="city" placeholder="city" required><br />
<label for="houseaddress">Houseaddress:</label><input type="text" name="houseaddress" id="houseaddress" placeholder="houseaddress" required><br />
<label for="phone">Phone:</label><input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" placeholder="phone" required><br />
<label for="email">E-mail:</label><input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="email" required><br />
```

client.class.php:

```
class Client{
    private $initials;
    private $name;
    private $surname;
    private $country;
    private $state;
    private $province;
    private $city;
    private $houseaddress;
    private $phone;
    private $email;


        public function getInitials() {
            return $this->initials;
        }

        public function getName() {
            return $this->name;
        }

        public function getSurname() {
            return $this->surname;
        }

        public function getCountry() {
            return $this->country;
        }

        public function getState() {
            return $this->state;
        }

        public function getProvince() {
            return $this->province;
        }

        public function getCity() {
            return $this->city;
        }

        public function getHouseaddress() {
            return $this->houseaddress;
        }

        public function getPhone() {
            return $this->phone;
        }

        public function getEmail() {
            return $this->email;
        }
        public function __construct($initials, $name, $surname, $country, $state, $province, $city, $houseaddress, $phone, $email) {
            $this->initials = $initials;
            $this->name = $name;
            $this->surname = $surname;
            $this->country = $country;
            $this->state = $state;
            $this->province = $province;
            $this->city = $city;
            $this->houseaddress = $houseaddress;
            $this->phone = $phone;
            $this->email = $email;
        }


        function setInitials($initials) {
            $this->initials = $initials;
        }

        function setName($name) {
            $this->name = $name;
        }

        function setSurname($surname) {
            $this->surname = $surname;
        }

        function setCountry($country) {
            $this->country = $country;
        }

        function setState($state) {
            $this->state = $state;
        }

        function setProvince($province) {
            $this->province = $province;
        }

        function setCity($city) {
            $this->city = $city;
        }

        function setHouseadress($houseaddress) {
            $this->houseaddress = $houseaddress;
        }

        function setPhone($phone) {
            $this->phone = $phone;
        }

        function setEmail($email) {
            $this->email = $email;
        }
        function getClientArray(){

        }
?>
```

database.php:

```
<?php


class Database {
    private $pdo;

    public function __construct() {
        // Connection information
        $host   = 'localhost:3307';
        $dbname = 'californiahotel';
        $user   = 'root';
        $pass   = 'usbw';

        // Attempt DB connection
        try
        {
            $this->pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $user, $pass);
            $this->pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            echo 'Successfully connected to the database!';
        }
        catch(PDOException $e)
        {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }

    }

    public function prepareRegistration($client){
            $initials = $client->getInitials();
            $name = $client->getName();
            $surname = $client->getSurname();
            $country = $client->getCountry();
            $state = $client->getState();
            $province = $client->getProvince();
            $city = $client->getCity();
            $houseaddress = $client->getHouseAddress();
            $phone = $client->getPhone();
            $email = $client->getEmail();
    //}
    //public function saveRegistration($client){
            $sql = "INSERT INTO client (Initials, Name, Surname, Country, State, Province, City, Houseadress, Phone, Email) VALUES(:Initials, :Name, :Surname, :Country, :State, :Province, :City, :Houseadress, :Phone, :Email)";
            $sth = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
            $sth->bindParam(':Initials', $initials);
            $sth->bindParam(':Name', $name);
            $sth->bindParam(':Surname', $surname);
            $sth->bindParam(':Country', $country);
            $sth->bindParam(':State', $state);
            $sth->bindParam(':Province', $province);
            $sth->bindParam(':City', $city);
            $sth->bindParam(':Houseaddress', $houseaddress);
            $sth->bindParam(':Phone', $phone);
            $sth->bindParam(':Email', $email);
            $sth->execute();

            //return $sql;
    }
```

saveregistration.php

```
$initials = $_POST['initials'];
$name = $_POST['firstname'];
$surname = $_POST['surname'];
$country = $_POST['country'];
$state = $_POST['state'];
$province = $_POST['province'];
$city = $_POST['city'];
$houseaddress = $_POST['houseaddress'];
$phone = (int)$_POST['phone'];
$email = $_POST['email'];

//$sql = "INSERT INTO client (Initials, Name, Surname, Country, State, Province, City, Houseadress, Email) VALUES('AJ', 'Arjan', 'Oskam', 'Holland', 'None', 'ZuidHolland', 'Boskoop', 'Laagboskoop53', '0615115309', 'arjanoskam97@gmail.com')";

echo $phone;
$client = new Client("", $initials, $name, $surname, $country, $state, $province, $city, $houseaddress, $phone, $email);
//var_dump($client);
//echo $client;
//$clientarray = (array)$client;
//$clientarrayprint = $client;
//foreach($client as $value) {
//  print $value . "<br />";
//}
//var_dump($clientarray);
$database = new Database();
$database->prepareRegistration($client);
//var_dump($client);
//$database->saveRegistration();
//header("Location: index.php");
```

Maybe 1 of you see the problem, but I can't find it!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you looked in the error logs?

Comment: Typo: Houseaddress vs Houseadress

Comment: Typo like @AlexK. pointed out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the constructor and how you are instantiating an object:

constructor:

```
public function __construct($initials, $name, $surname, $country, $state, $province, $city, $houseaddress, $phone, $email) {
```

new object:

```
$client = new Client("", $initials, $name, $surname, $country, $state, $province, $city, $houseaddress, $phone, $email);
                     ^^^ why is this here?
```

You are calling your constructor with one parameter too many, you should remove the first emtpy string:

```
$client = new Client($initials, $name, $surname, $country, $state, $province, $city, $houseaddress, $phone, $email);
```

Comment: Forgot to mention! : The database has a column ClientID!

Comment: That does not matter when you construct your object. The first parameter in the constructor is `$initials` so when you call it, it should be the same.

Comment: @ArjanOskam yeah jeroen is right you should remove that extra params, its all most like you got it confused with an INSERT query. your code will be looking for that constructor you don't have and `$client` object will not be able to be created